# If a human's lungs stretched to the lower abdomen, what would it feel like?

Tags: biology, anatomy, life

I was considering a human-like race of aliens, where their lungs are huge. Their lungs would reach to the lower abdomen. Due to the science-magic of the setting, they can survive just fine with shrunken guts, hearts, livers and other organs. But I don't want to handwave the question of large lungs that stretch to the abdomen.

If humans did have lungs that filled much of their abdomen, instead of jotting slightly into the abdomen like in reality, what would happen? Would it knock the wind out of you ever time you bended over, cause you a lot of pain if someone hit you in the belly? Would it make life unlivable?

Comment: Why should your body causes pain for something which is physiologically normal? You are not bothered by your heartbeat or by your lungs expansion, or not?

Comment: @L.Dutch is right, something that's normal to the body would not cause pain during any normal function, such as bending over.  Most likely the body would be designed to accomodate the bend without compromising the lungs, but at worst, bending over would reduce lung capacity by, what, 33%ish?  You'd feel short of breath while bent over, but not necessarily uncomfortable.  By the time you hit adulthood, you'd likely not even notice it was happening.

Comment: What is "science-magic"??

Comment: "*If humans did have lungs that filled much of their abdomen*". A normal human who's lungs suddenly enlarged?

Comment: Note there are several ways to make lungs work not just the negative pressure system mammals use, dinosaurs and birds use direct muscle attachment, there are muscles that pull the lungs, and later air sacs, open. Crocodiles use a liver piston system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aliens had the same skeleton as humans, the part of the lungs that stretches into the lower abdomen wouldn't be useful.

The ribs not only protect our lungs from punches, they are like a rack that holds the lungs in place. If the lungs are torn from their attachments to the ribs, they collapse and cannot fill with air on their own.

Abdominal muscles might be suitable to hold lungs up, but they move in the wrong direction to ventilate the lungs. And, as you correctly guessed, your aliens wouldn't be able to utilize this additional lung capacity when bending and moving compresses the abdomen.

To give an alien more lung capacity I see the following possibilities:

- Give them better lungs. There are different lung types in amphibians, reptiles and mammals. The air sacs in birds play a vital role in breathing, although they are not lungs. Make the alien lungs just better.
- Add more lower ribs. This makes their movements somewhat stiffer because - unlike with snakes - the hip bones limit how much they can bend until hips and ribs are in each others way.
- Stretch the upper torso longer to make room for longer ribs
- Increase the volume of the upper torso. That would result in the quite typical style of grey aliens [like this one](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/stargate/images/d/d3/Asgard-LT.JPG/revision/latest?cb=20100116045507)

Comment: Yeah having a gap in the ribs is a mammal thing anyway the normal (basal) plan for  vertebrates is to have have ribs all the way down to the pelvis. Mammals,  need a gap for our weird breathing mechanism (and oddly crocodiles with their liver piston system).

Comment: I'd add air sacks in bones to the list, like birds do.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to make a guess, I would say they have more flexible spines like a snake, and ribs that extend down their entire torso.[Snake lungs](http://www.reptilesmagazine.com/Kid-Corner/Beyond-Beginners/Snake-Anatomy-Respiratory/) is a basic idea of how snake lungs work, including how they tend to have only a lung on one side, and use passive respiration instead of active like humans. You can mix and match those, and have your aliens be active breathers with two separately sized lungs, a full lung and a half lung to make room for extra organs.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you about the feeling of having lungs in your abdomen, I can tell you about when your abdomen gets pushed up to your lungs.  Pregnancy does this.  The uterus expands more than any other (pre-existing) human organ.  While a lot of the extra size goes outward, making the belly huge, it also pushes the abdominal organs in various directions.

It's pretty common (though not universal) for pregnant women to be short of breath in the third trimester.  Not because of carrying the extra weight but because the uterus and other organs are pushing into the space where the lungs are trying to expand.

It's not dangerous but it does limit your activities.  I agree with other responses that talk about the importance of the rib cage in protecting the lungs.  Extra long lungs would only be useful in specific situations where they could actually expand.  When swimming perhaps?

Note that it would also make pregnancy really really uncomfortable!